# Is there any example of a system where an equilibrium state can be reached starting from a nonequilibrium state by reversible processes only?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Is there any example of a system where an equilibrium state can be reached starting from a nonequilibrium state by reversible processes only?

Put another way, is there any nonequilibrium state which has the same entropy as one of an equilibrium states of the system?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a reversible process in this context?

Comment: @BySymmetry any process that does not produce entropy.